# How can I convert grid coordinates back to (x,y)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am creating a game in PyQt5 where the user can click inside a grid to form squares. If the user chooses four grid spaces that form a square, the corners are connected with lines. My code currently looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColo, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication

CELL_COUNT = 8
CELL_SIZE = 50
GRID_ORIGINX = 150
GRID_ORIGINY = 150
W_WIDTH = 700
W_HEIGHT = 700

class TribeSquares(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT)
    a = ''
    self.__board = [[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a],[a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]]
    self.__row = None
    self.__col = None
    self.__clicked0 = []
    self.show()
```

First, I converted (x,y) coordinates to grid coordinates.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.__x = event.x()
    self.__y = event.y()
    self.__row = (event.y() - GRID_ORIGINY) // CELL_SIZE
    self.__col = (event.x() - GRID_ORIGINX) // CELL_SIZE
    row = self.__row
    col = self.__col
    self.update()
```

For another method, I want to convert (row,col) back to (x,y). I tried reversing the process and doing it like this:

```
def cell2coord(self, row, col):
    return ((row * CELL_SIZE) + GRID_ORIGINX, (col * CELL_SIZE) + GRID_ORIGINY)
```

Next, in the paintEvent, I try to call the method I created.

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    for r in range(CELL_COUNT):
        for c in range(CELL_COUNT):
            qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 1))
            qp.drawRect(CELL_SIZE * c + GRID_ORIGINX, CELL_SIZE * r + GRID_ORIGINY, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE)
            if (r, c) in self.__clicked0:
                qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(40, 85, 66), 1))
                qp.setBrush(QColor(40, 85, 66))
                qp.drawRect(CELL_SIZE * c + GRID_ORIGINX + 7.5, CELL_SIZE * r + GRID_ORIGINY + 7.5, 35, 35)
                qp.setBrush(QColor(237, 237, 237))
            elif (r, c) in self.__clicked1:
                qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(231, 181, 71), 1))
                qp.setBrush(QColor(231, 181, 71))
                qp.drawRect(CELL_SIZE * c + GRID_ORIGINX + 7.5, CELL_SIZE * r + GRID_ORIGINY + 7.5, 35, 35)
                qp.setBrush(QColor(237, 237, 237))
    for (r, c) in self.__clicked0:
        x,y = self.cell2coord(r,c)
        x2,y2 = self.cell2coord(self.__row, self.__col)
        if r == self.__row or c == self.__col:
            qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(40, 85, 66), 5))
            qp.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2)
    for (r, c) in self.__clicked1:
        if r == self.__row or c == self.__col:
            qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(231, 181, 71), 5))
            qp.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2)
    qp.end()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = TribeSquares()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But it didn't work. The lines are not showing up in the right spot and connecting the squares created by user clicks in the grid. What can I do?

Comment: Edited for clarity!

Comment: That was a mistake. Still getting used to this site. I added it back again, is this right or not concise enough?

Comment: Just the center of the cell?

Comment: Oh, I see. Anywhere that's roughly in the center of the cell would be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you have built the rectangles to paint in the `paintEvent` method, you could do it to get the `QRect`, and then use its `center()` method, and then get its coordinates.

```
def cell2coord(self, row, col):
    center_pos = QRect(CELL_SIZE * c + GRID_ORIGINX, CELL_SIZE * r + GRID_ORIGINY, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE).center()
    return center_pos.x(), center_pos.y()
```

Comment: It wouldn't show up at first, but I tried swapping out r and c for row and col, and enclosing the return statement in parentheses, and that ran fine. The lines are disappearing after the user clicks elsewhere, but it's still much better than before. Thank you!